# jQuery take of focus on textbox on page load

Tags: jquery, autofocus

i have search form in my page.
On page load it is on focus by default.
Cursor is active in it.

can i take of the focus of the textbox.
on page load?
So that i don't have cursor in it by default?

Comment: How is the focus being set in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this, just add hidden input:button tag field somewhere at the top of body, it will gain focus, but avoid any form, since you don't want it to submit when user clicks on Enter key

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$(function() {
    $('input#some_id').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the focus somewhere else, like this?

```
$(function(){
  $("body").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$("#searchBox").blur();
});
```